# Adding compile-time definitions in Kconfig in Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kbuild

I understand there is an option to add compile-time macros/definitions to the Kconfig file that can be used in the code.

(For example, some definition of a constant, like a #define).

Answer (score 10):

The Kconfig values are passed as Makefile defines.  Also, all selected Kconfig values are put in a header file and passed to the assembler and 'C' code.  So, you do not do this directly in the Kconfig file, but can do it in the Makefile or source.

### Kconfig

```
config MY_DEFINE
    bool "Select to get some DEFINE"
    default y
    help
      This is a config define that is sent to both make
      and defined in a config.h header.
```

### Makefile

```
ifeq ($(CONFIG_MY_DEFINE),y)
KBUILD_CFLAGS   += -DTHE_REAL_DEAL=1  # THE_REAL_DEAL now '1' in C files.
endif
```

### Source

```
#ifdef CONFIG_MY_DEFINE
#define THE_REAL_DEAL 1
#endif
```

So, the **Kconfig** section defines the user interface information.  The `.config` is makefile syntax, which is output by *menuconfig*, etc.  This is sourced when you type `make`.  Ie, all the stuff selected by *menuconfig* or another tool is available in Makefiles.  The **Kconfig** variable has a **CONFIG_** prefix added.

You can choose either the **Makefile** or the **Source** sections to get your define.  If you want to select a range, then you can pass the value of `CONFIG_MY_DEFINE` to the compiler.  Ie, including almost any kernel header will include *config.h* and the 'C' value `CONFIG_MY_DEFINE` will be set to whatever the user selected in the range.

---

See the [kbuild wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kbuild/info) for more, which mainly references the [kernel's kbuild documentation](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/kbuild).

Comment: Newer kernels have a macro `#if IS_ENABLED(CONFIG_MY_DEFINE)`, that will handle *modules* (or three state variables).  However, it isn't as relative to a generic *define*, but it wouldn't hurt to use it.

Comment: Of course, if just the presence of a define is enough, you can use it directly.  However, the kernel variables will be 'y,n,m', and better handled by macro mentioned in the comment above.